# Mouseover event timeout

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mouseover, mouseleave

Here you find the csv file https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ekwalkwqahl806/PeriodicTable.csv?dl=0

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
  <head>

    <style>
    rect.bordered {
      stroke: grey;
      stroke-width:2px;
    }
    text.mono {
      font-size: 9pt;
      font-family: Consolas;
      fill: blue;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="chart" ></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
//cree les variables
      var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 30 },
          width = 960 - 30 ,
          height = 430 - 50 ,
          espacecases = 3
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 18),//changer la taille du tableau
          ys = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"],
          xs = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"];

// cree la base du svg
      var svg = d3.select("#chart")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + 90)                                              //+70 por agrandire vers la droite
                  .attr("height", height + 250)                                           //+200 pour agrandir l espace por l immage
                  .append("g") // crée un groupe contenant le tp
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + 30 +"," + 50+ ")");// bouger le tp pour avoir de la place pour les axes

//axe des y
      var yLabels = svg.selectAll(".yLabel")
                       .data(ys)
                       .enter()
                       .append("text")
                       .text(function (d) { return d; })
                       .attr("x", 0)
                       .attr("y", function (d, i) { return i * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases); })             // + espacecases +10 car rectangle
                       .style("text-anchor", "end")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
                       .attr("class", "yLabel mono axis");

// graduation axe des x
      var xLabels = svg.selectAll(".xLabel")
                       .data(xs)
                       .enter().append("text")
                       .text(function(d) { return d; })
                       .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * (gridSize+ espacecases); }) //function (d,i) avec d=data et i=index of data
                       .attr("y", 0)
                       .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
                       .attr("class", "xLabel mono axis");

// prendre les données du fichier csv

      var newlist = function(csvFile){
          d3.csv(csvFile,function(d){
            return {
              AtomicNumber: d.AtomicNumber,
              Element:      d.Element,
              Symbole:      d.Symbole,
              AtomicWeight: d.AtomicWeight,
              Period:       d.Period,
              Group:        d.Group,
              Phase:        d.Phase,
              MostStableCrystal: d.MostStableCrystal,
              Type:         d.Type,
              IonicRadius:  d.IonicRadius,
              AtomicRadius: d.AtomicRadius,
              Electronegativity: d.Electronegativity,
              FirstIonizationPotential: d.FirstIonizationPotential,
              Density:      d.Density,
              MeltingPointK: d.MeltingPointK,
              BoilingPointK: d.BoilingPointK,
              Isotopes:     d.Isotopes,
              Discoverer:   d.Discoverer,
              YearofDiscovery: d.YearofDiscovery,
              SpecificHeatCapacity: d.SpecificHeatCapacity,
              ElectronConfiguration: d.ElectronConfiguration,
              DisplayRow: d.DisplayRow,
              DisplayColumn: d.DisplayColumn,};
          },

// traitement des données

        function(error,data) {
          var cards = svg.selectAll(".DisplayRow")
                         .data(data, function(d) {
                           return d.DisplayRow+':'+d.DisplayColumn;
                         });

          var word = function(d) {return (d.Element) ; };

          var g = cards.enter()
                       .append('g')
                       .attr("id", function(d){return d.Type})
                       .append('g')
                       .attr("id",function(d) {return "element"+(d.AtomicNumber)})
                       .on("click", function(d) { if (d.Symbole!="Hg") { return window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+word(d), '_blank')}
                                                  else  { return window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+word(d)+"_(element)", '_blank') };
                                                                   });


              g.attr("transform", function(d){
                                 var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                                     y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                        return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
                        });

              g.append("rect")
               .attr("rx", 4) // arrondir les cases des elements
               .attr("ry", 4) // arrondir les cases des element
               .attr("class", "xpos bordered") // class=style definit dans le head
               .attr("width", gridSize) //largeur des cases d elements
               .attr("height", gridSize+10) //Hauteur...       //+10 pour faire rectangle
               .transition()
               .duration(2000)
               .style("fill", function(d) {
                     if (d.Type =="Transition Metal") {return "LightSkyBlue"}
                     else if (d.Type =="Alkali Metal")   { return "royalblue" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Noble Gas")   { return "Salmon" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Metalloid")   { return "grey" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Metal")   { return "Peru" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Nonmetal")   { return "gold" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Halogen")   { return "orange" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Alkaline Earth Metal")   { return "hotpink" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Lanthanide")   { return "YellowGreen" }
                     else if (d.Type =="Actinide")   { return "PapayaWhip" }
                     else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 112)   { return "LightSkyBlue" }
                     else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 116)   { return "Peru" }
                     else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 117)   { return "orange" }
                ;}) ;


              g.append("text")
               .text(function(d){
                  return (d.AtomicNumber);
                })
               .style("font-size",10)
               .attr("x", +10)
               .attr("y", +10)
               .style("text-anchor", "middle");

               g.append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                  return (d.Symbole);
                })
                .style("font-size",30)
                .attr("x", +25)
                .attr("y", 40)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .on("mouseover", function(d){
                  var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                      y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                         d3.select("body")
                           .select("#element"+(d.AtomicNumber))
                           .transition()
                           .ease("quad")
                           .duration("500")
                           .attr("transform", "translate(" + 200 +"," + 20+ ") scale( 2.5 )")
                })
                .on("mouseleave", function(d){
                  var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                      y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                         d3.select("body")
                           .select("#element"+(d.AtomicNumber))
                           .transition()
                           .ease("quad")
                           .duration("300")
                           .attr("transform", "translate("+ x +"," + y+ ") scale( 1 )")
                });

               g.append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                  return (d.AtomicWeight) ;
                })
                .style("font-size",7)
                .attr("x", +25)
                .attr("y", +50)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(word);


               g.append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                 return (d.AtomicWeight) ;
               })
                .style("font-size",7)
                .attr("x", +25)
                .attr("y",+57)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle");

               g.append("text")
                .text(function(d) {
                  return (d.YearofDiscovery) ;
                 })
                .style("font-size",7)
                .attr("x", +40)
                .attr("y",+10)
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text(function(d) { return (d.YearofDiscovery) ; });

                //d3.select("body").selectAll("#Nonmetal").remove();
                //d3.select("body").select("#element1").remove();


     });

      };

newlist("PeriodicTable.csv")
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I created a periodic table from a csv.file. I ploted all element in a svg and each element has group whith its own id. Now i'm trying to display a bigger element when the mouse stay on the atomic symbol. But this bigger element is unstable, it's blinking(going and coming back). I think a good way to fix that is to add a duration to mouseover but i have no idea how i can do that. If you think this is not the problem and there is another way, i'm open!

[image: Table of elements output image]

Comment: do you have a demo somewhere?

Comment: Where can I upload a demo? Or the script?

Comment: on the post editor is an icon that looks like < > to insert html/css/script. But you can also give me a link if you prefer

Comment: Edit done everything is here.

Comment: sorry to say csv fails to load.... cross origin not allowed from stacksnippets... then the script also fails

Comment: This why I added a link to the csv file, if you want to try your own.

Comment: the problem is with script or css... I need to see the whole thing in action before can even start to think about where the trouble is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the element that handles the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events is one of the elements that is being repositioned due to the transformation. So once it starts moving away from the mouse it triggers the `mouseleave` event and comes back.

They way i solved it is to add the initial positioning on the outer `g` element as well as the mouse events handling. You will also need to add a transparent rectangle inside that so that it has contents once you start moving the inner `g` element.

So the changed part is

```
     var gg = cards.enter()
                   .append('g')
                   .attr("id", function(d){return d.Type}),
           g = gg.append('g')
                   .attr("id",function(d) {return "element"+(d.AtomicNumber)})
                   .on("click", function(d) { if (d.Symbole!="Hg") { return window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+word(d), '_blank')}
                                              else  { return window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+word(d)+"_(element)", '_blank') };
                                                               });


          gg.attr("transform", function(d){
                             var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                                 y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                    return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
                    })
            .append('rect')
            .attr("width", gridSize) //largeur des cases d elements
            .attr("height", gridSize+10) //Hauteur...       //+10 pour faire rectangle
            .style("fill","transparent");

          g.append("rect")
           .attr("rx", 4) // arrondir les cases des elements
           .attr("ry", 4) // arrondir les cases des element
           .attr("class", "xpos bordered") // class=style definit dans le head
           .attr("width", gridSize) //largeur des cases d elements
           .attr("height", gridSize+10) //Hauteur...       //+10 pour faire rectangle
           .transition()
           .duration(2000)
           .style("fill", function(d) {
                 if (d.Type =="Transition Metal") {return "LightSkyBlue"}
                 else if (d.Type =="Alkali Metal")   { return "royalblue" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Noble Gas")   { return "Salmon" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Metalloid")   { return "grey" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Metal")   { return "Peru" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Nonmetal")   { return "gold" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Halogen")   { return "orange" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Alkaline Earth Metal")   { return "hotpink" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Lanthanide")   { return "YellowGreen" }
                 else if (d.Type =="Actinide")   { return "PapayaWhip" }
                 else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 112)   { return "LightSkyBlue" }
                 else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 116)   { return "Peru" }
                 else if (d.AtomicNumber <= 117)   { return "orange" }
            ;}) ;


          g.append("text")
           .text(function(d){
              return (d.AtomicNumber);
            })
           .style("font-size",10)
           .attr("x", +10)
           .attr("y", +10)
           .style("text-anchor", "middle");

           g.append("text")
            .text(function(d) {
              return (d.Symbole);
            })
            .style("font-size",30)
            .attr("x", +25)
            .attr("y", 40)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle");

          gg.on("mouseover", function(d){
              var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                  y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                     d3.select("body")
                       .select("#element"+(d.AtomicNumber))
                       .transition()
                       .ease("quad")
                       .duration("500")
                       .attr("transform", "translate(" + (200-x) +"," + (20-y)+ ") scale( 2.5 )")
            })
            .on("mouseleave", function(d){
              var x = (d.DisplayColumn - 1) * (gridSize + espacecases),
                  y = (d.DisplayRow - 1) * (gridSize + 10 + espacecases);
                     d3.select("body")
                       .select("#element"+(d.AtomicNumber))
                       .transition()
                       .ease("quad")
                       .duration("300")
                       .attr("transform", "scale( 1 )")
            });
```

Demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/4jyRLSVuVMv3rfnwbJc5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attaching the mouse event handlers to the `<text>` element for each chemical symbol.  That's not the best idea because you will get mouseover firing when you over the solid parts of the letters, and mouseleave will fire when you are over the gaps between and inside letters.  That will be the reason for your flickering issues I think.

What you should do instead is attach the events to the rectangular background of each chemical element.

You will find then that mouseleave will fire when you are over the text.
To fix that, add `pointer-events: none` to the CSS for all the text elements that are inside the rectangles.  Or add the attribute `pointer-events="none"` if you prefer to do it that way.